# Microsoft Access Checkbox with SQL Backend Does Not Update

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I've been researching it and have found many similar cases... but none exactly the same. I've tried a lot of different resolutions in the previous cases mentioned and none of them fixed this one.

I just recently did a SQL Server Migration and am now troubleshooting the issues that have sprung up with the new SQL back end. This is the last one that I can not figure out:

I have a split form with a check box control, bound to a SQL Server View through a DSN-Less connection. Before the migration the Bound Access Query could not be updated... so I programatically updated the forms checkboxes through VBA using two different methods:

1. Was a check all/ check none checkbox which when clicked checked or unchecked all of the checkboxes in the datasheet.
2. Gave the ability for the user to check or uncheck each individual checkbox by using the checkboxes Mouse_Down Event.

Here is the code for each of the two methods:

```vb
    ' Check All/ Check None
    Dim rsSelect As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsUpdate As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim CurrDb As Database
    Dim currFilter As String

On Error GoTo chkSelect_Click_Error

   ' Capture current filter
    If Me.FilterOn Then currFilter = Me.Filter
    Set rsSelect = Me.RecordsetClone

    Set CurrDb = CurrentDb

     rsSelect.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rsSelect.EOF
         SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblTimesheet WHERE [TimesheetID] = " & rsSelect("TimesheetID")
        Set rsUpdate = CurrDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
        If Not rsUpdate.EOF Then
            If Me.chkSelect Then
                With rsUpdate
                    .Edit
                    rsUpdate("TimesheetSelect") = True
                    .Update
                End With
            Else
                 With rsUpdate
                    .Edit
                    rsUpdate("TimesheetSelect") = False
                    .Update
                End With
            End If
        End If
        rsSelect.MoveNext
     Loop
    rsUpdate.Close
    rsSelect.Close
    Me.Requery
    If currFilter > "" Then
        Me.Filter = currFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
    If Me.chkSelect Then
        Me.lblSelect.Caption = "Select None"
    Else
        Me.lblSelect.Caption = "Select All"
    End If

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

chkSelect_Click_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure chkSelect_Click of VBA Document Form_frmTimesheetSummary"
```

And Secondly:

```vb
    ' Check/ Uncheck Individual Checkbox
    Dim rsUpdate As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim CurrDb As Database
    Dim currFilter As String

   ' Capture current filter
    If Me.FilterOn Then currFilter = Me.Filter

    Set CurrDb = CurrentDb
     SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblTimesheet WHERE [TimesheetID] = " & Me.TimesheetID
    Set rsUpdate = CurrDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    If Not rsUpdate.EOF Then
        If Me.TimesheetSelect Then
            With rsUpdate
                .Edit
                rsUpdate("TimesheetSelect") = False
                .Update
            End With
        Else
             With rsUpdate
                .Edit
                rsUpdate("TimesheetSelect") = True
                .Update
            End With
        End If
    End If


    rsUpdate.Close
    Me.Form.Requery
    'Me.Repaint
    Me.Refresh
    If currFilter > "" Then
        Me.Filter = currFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
```

Both of these procedures worked with an Access back end... but the "Check Individual" procedure refuses to work now. When I check a checkbox it does update the SQL Backend... but the control itself refuses to update the new status... I of course have tried Requery, but also Repaint and Refresh and it refuses to update unless I completely close the form and reopen it again.

The real kicker in all this is that the Check All method still works! I've spent hours on this and am hoping to get some fresh eyes on it because it should be working if the backend is updating!!

**ADDITIONAL NOTES ADDED LATER:** In response to some of the great reasoning below I feel I should include this additional notes:

1. I am using SQL Server 2012 and the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 Driver for my connection string.
2. I am using Microsoft Access 2010 32 bit
3. The SQL Server field is a bit I've removed all nulls and set allow nulls to 'no' with a default of 0

Comment: I don't have my old notes available at the moment, but I seem to remember your issue when dealing with boolean values when we converted to SQL Server. I think the solution was to use 0 or 1 instead of True False. I will try to find my conversion notes...

Comment: Not senile yet... :) Look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/03/06/access-to-sql-server-migration-understanding-data-type-conversions.aspx   and find: Handling Booleans, bits, and True

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: But if `TimesheetSelect` were datatype `bit`, wouldn't the first procedure not work either?

Comment: @Andre: I was too focused on the 'moved to SQL Server...' and was looking at 'some' of the references to True/False which still need to be changed. I should have read the problem better. So, 'TimesheetSelect' is a bound control and not being updated. Anthony, you use 'Click' event for one, but 'MouseDown' for other? Did you know that the value of 'TimesheetSelect' doesn't change until AFTER MouseDown has fired? So your check for True is off.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn  Thanks for the replies. I've tried True/ False, -1/0 and 1/0 and all of them produce the same result. The reason for the different Events is due to the fact that the Check All is unbound so the click event works. The Check Individual is bound to an updatable recordset and therefore the Click Event never fires since the recordset can not update... Thus I had to place it in the Mouse Down event.

Comment: (1) As mentioned before, the MouseDown will reflect the value BEFORE the change (if false and you press mousedown, this code will see the false value), but that doesn't impact display. (2) If you shut down app and reopen, does correct value show? If so, there is either a timing issue or your refresh is not working. (3) Does the filter you are saving have any mention of the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who posted... the answer that ended working for me in this case was ditching the split form... I had heard it suggested that split forms can be problematic at times so redesigned the form in a standard Parent/ Subform setup which completely resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some things come to mind:

1) You can replace the whole `rsUpdate` construction in the second procedure by this:

```vb
SQL = "UPDATE tblTimesheet SET TimesheetSelect = " & _
      IIf(Me.TimesheetSelect, "0", "-1") & _
      " WHERE TimesheetID = " & Me.TimesheetID
CurrDb.Execute SQL, dbSeeChanges
```

It depends on your `TimesheetSelect` datatype whether you should use "-1" or "1".

2) `Me.Form.Requery` should be `Me.Requery`.

3) If it still doesn't work, adding a TIMESTAMP column to `tblTimesheet` might help Access recognize that the record was changed. This is generally a good thing to have, but *shouldn't* be necessary.

Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861581/3820271
`tblTimesheet` *does* have a primary key, doesn't it?

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't thought about executing the update through SQL... I'll give it a try now. Yes... Me.Form.Requery was not how it was initially... that's just a reflection of my many different attempts to get the form to requery thus I've also tried Docmd.Requery and lastly the Me.Form.Requery... Yes the table has both a timestamp and Primary Key. Also the datatype is a bit.

Comment: Bummed out... it didn't get it either.

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs: If the datatype is `bit`, you need to use `1` instead of `True` or `-1`. You said you tried that, but perhaps update the code in your question to the current version?

Answer (score 1):

If Andre's suggestions don't solve it, instead of Me.Requery, try resetting the form's recordsource. Me.RecordSource = .
You don't say what version of SQL Server you are using or which ODBC driver. Make sure you are using the correct ODBC Driver for your version of SQL Server and not the default 'SQL Server' driver.

Comment: Good point. I am using SQL Server 2012 with the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 Driver... I've already adjusted the mistake of the default SQL Server driver in my DSN-Less Connection string when working out my issues on dates.

Comment: Resetting the Record Source was another good idea... but unfortunately didn't work in this case.

Comment: Try adding DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache before the requery or resetting of the recordsource.